# If statement not working; need assistance

Tags: python

***CODE***

```
year = int(input("What year were you born in ?"))

month = int(input('What month were you born in (USE MONTH NUMBER)?'))

if(month = [1,2,3]):
    print("You were born in the winter")
if (month <4-6):
      print("You were born in the spring")
if (month <7-9):
      print("You were born in the summer")
elif (month <10-12):
      print ("You were born in the fall")
```

***OUTPUT***

```
File "main.py", line 7

if(month = [1,2,3]) :
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: use `in` instead of `=`   Also, comparison operator is `==` not `=`

Comment: Use `==` to compare, and use `=` to assign.

Comment: In the future; use a descriptive title and explain the problem in the question. Don't use a very generic-sounding title as others who have the same issue as you will have no way to search this problem.

Comment: What kind of “assistance” do you need? The Python documentation is [right here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), a tutorial is [right there](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements). What are _we_ supposed to do here?

Comment: I recommend you spend some time reviewing this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert them into a list to check.

Try this code.

```
year = int(input("What year were you born in ?"))

month = int(input('What month were you born in (USE MONTH NUMBER)?'))

if   (month in [1,2,3]):
      print("You were born in the winter")
elif (month in [4, 5, 6]):
      print("You were born in the spring")
elif (month in [7,8,9]):
      print("You were born in the summer")
elif (month in [10,11,12]):
      print ("You were born in the fall")
else:
      print ('Incorrect month')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if month = [1,2,3] :
    print("You were born in the winter")
```

*May Work

Comment: you need to give `==` for comparison.

Comment: @JoeFerndz Why? Your answer already correctly uses `in`. `month == [1, 2, 3]` is always going to be `False` in this code.

Comment: You are correct. In this case it has to be `in` as the comparison is against a list. The `==` comparison operator will NOT work in this case. the value of `month` cannot be a list as the input is an integer value.